# Kotlin in VScode

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code

today I tried to run easy Kotlin code in VScode, but there is error:

```
cd "c:\Users\<MyPcUser>\<SomeMoreFolders>\Visual Studio\Kotlin (There is the file saved) \" && kotlinc main.kt -include-runtime -d main.jar && java -jar main.jar
'kotlinc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have installed "Code Runner" extension and "Kotlin Language" extension. I searched on the internet and youtube, but in tutorials, it worked for them.

Can somebody help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue and on both of my linux and windows machies. And the fix is essentially the same. **You need to add kotlin compiler to your PATH variable**.
I suppose you also have your kotlin installed from previously installing IntelliJ IDEA so to help you find it path is probably something like:

"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\bin"

After you added it to path restart PC if you are on Windows or logout/login if you are on linux

To test execute this command in terminal

```
kotlinc -version
```

Should return something like

```
kotlinc-jvm 1.7.10-release-334 (JRE 11.0.16+11-LTS-199)
```

and your should be able to run from VS code